# Novel about a group of teens who get trapped on a space station and send video blogs to Earth

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading this one a couple years ago, having found it on the New Releases shelf of the library. I don't think it was released any earlier than 2010... I'm thinking 2011 or 2012. The book was written in an adult style but I think was categorized as YA because of the ages of the characters.

The plot involved a group of teens somehow ending up on a space station (they stowed away(?) to get famous) and didn't realize that they'd be unable to leave for the next several years. To maintain their fame during that time, they posted video blogs about their life to send to Earth.

I remember it because of the interesting elements of worldbuilding, including that the birth rate had gone way down because it was too much paperwork to get your mandatory birth control turned off. Everyone lived comfortably because most jobs were done by robots, except if you actually wanted to have a job, you got paid more. Celebrities got paid the most, which is why these kids wanted to somehow become famous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Losers in Space](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11737295-losers-in-space)* by John Barnes, 2012

> " and about ten hours of interviews and filling out forms, and is good
>   for only three months) has caused the birth rate to fall..."
>
> "Susan and her friends are celebutantes. Their lives are powered by
>   media awareness, fed by engineered meals, and underscored by cynicism.
>   Everyone has a rating; the more viewers who ID you, the better. So
>   Susan and her almost-boyfriend Derlock cook up a surefire plan: the
>   nine of them will visit a Mars-bound spaceship and stow away."

Comment: 3 months? What in the world? What kind of birth control is this? If you're coming off the pill, you might not regain your fertility for much longer than that. No wonder the birth rate has fallen so much.